# Is there any better way to optimize dividing by a window function in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say we want to calculate the proportion of cities that each state has within our dataset. e.g. Nevada has 25% of the total number of cities in the table.

Table Schema:

```
state - string of state name
city - string of city name
```

My answer is below, is there any better way to optimize this without having to resort to a subquery? (my code works btw).

```
SELECT
  counts/sum(counts) over () as perc,
  state
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      count(city) AS counts,
      state
    FROM
      table
    GROUP BY
      state
  ) t1
```

Comment: You can't call an aggregate function from within an aggregate function. count(city)/sum(count(city)) is a no go. You have to do one at a time for each level of aggregation, thus, a subquery.

Answer (score 2):

Just select the amount of cities once from your table, [set it as a variable](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/set-variable.html) and then use it:

```
SET @TOTAL = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM EXAMPLE_DATA);
SELECT COUNT(*)/@TOTAL, STATE FROM EXAMPLE_DATA GROUP BY State;
```

Where I used the following DDL:

```
CREATE Table EXAMPLE_DATA
(
STATE varchar(255),
CITY varchar(255)
);

INSERT INTO EXAMPLE_DATA (State, City) VALUES("Bavaria", "Munich");
INSERT INTO EXAMPLE_DATA (State, City) VALUES("Bavaria", "Ingolstadt");
INSERT INTO EXAMPLE_DATA (State, City) VALUES("Bavaria", "Eichstätt");
INSERT INTO EXAMPLE_DATA (State, City) VALUES("Berlin", "Berlin");
INSERT INTO EXAMPLE_DATA (State, City) VALUES("Saxonia", "Leipzig");
INSERT INTO EXAMPLE_DATA (State, City) VALUES("Saxonia", "Dresden");
```

Results in:

```
COUNT(*)/@TOTAL STATE
0.5000 Bavaria
0.1667 Berlin
0.3333 Saxonia
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is "yes".  You can use window functions:

```
SELECT state, count(*) AS counts,
       COUNT(*) / SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER () as ratio
FROM table
GROUP BY state;
```

Note that you have not provided sample data.  I am guessing that `city` is never `NULL`, so `COUNT(*)` is equivalent to `COUNT(city)`.  If `city` can be `NULL`, then use `COUNT(city)`.